# Switching MOSFET with isolated gate

Tags: mosfet, isolation

I am trying to isolate the battery which powers the gate control circuitry from the battery which powers the hight-current load being switched by the MOSFET. Here is the basic circuit configuration:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp5paA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Do the sources V1 and V2 need to share a ground in order for the MOSFET to switch on and off, or will the circuit function as is.

Comment: What what controls a MOSFET is the voltage DIFFERENCE between the gate and source. Not the voltage at the gate relative to ground because the MOSFET cannot see the voltage at ground. How can it?

Comment: V1 or V2 needn't be grounded - one or both might be a battery. V1 & V2 must *share a connection*, most often at the MOSfet source.

Comment: If you are not going to switch fast, there are purpose made gate-driving optocouplers for the very purpose. Look into the Vishay VOM-family.

Comment: V1 and M1 must share a ground. This is the correct way to look at it. Otherwise V1 won't be able to turn on M1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MOSFET turns on when a voltage is applied between its Gate and Source. In your circuit there is no path from the negative side of V1 to the MOSFET Source, so it won't turn on. All that will happen is the entire circuit (M1/Rload/V2) going up and down in time with V1.

You don't need an actual ground, but you do need to get M1's Gate and Source to the same voltage as is across V1. If for some reason that cannot be done by connecting the two 'grounds' directly together  (eg. one side is connected to AC mains, or the MOSFET is switching the 'high' side of the power supply) then you have a few options:-

1. A level shifting MOSFET driver such as the [LTC7001](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc7001.html#product-overview), which creates a local output 'ground' using a charge pump to raise the voltage. This still requires a connection between the two circuits somewhere, but voltage on the MOSFET can 'float' relative to their shared connection.
2. An [optocoupler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opto-isolator) which uses its isolated transistor as part of a driver circuit powered from the FET circuit.
3. A photovoltaic MOSFET driver such as the Panasonic [APV1121SZ](https://b2b-api.panasonic.eu/file_stream/pids/fileversion/619), which produces the required Gate voltage directly without needing any circuit powered from the FET side.

Answer (score 1):

Negative terminals of both batteries should be connected together (share wire) -- otherwise there is no electrical path to charge **GATE**.